# how to fix commit unmodified files on SVN server using sharpsvn

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

In my .net application , I am using sharpsvn to upload files to sever and download file from server.
Even user does not know we are using sharpsvn /svn server for upload/ download files, he just wanted to download and upload files from/on server.
But some time he uploads not changed  file  (he wanted to add unchanged file) and make file revisions
but here is the problem our code is broken because sharpsvn canot commit unchanged file
and user got error while upload unchanged file
how can I handle this

Comment: Thanks for answer actually I am very new in SVN and sharpsvn ,can you explain me in detail how I can do that, thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You can trick this by updating a subversion property on the file, perhaps with some name you reserve for this purpose and hide for the user.

Comment: Thanks for answer actually   I am very  new in SVN and sharpsvn ,can you explain me in detail how I can do that, thanks in advanced

Comment: @huijben which property i can use?

Comment: You can use any file property you like. E.g. just use 'my:update-trigger' and increment the integer inside or something like that.